# How to get PHP to stop automatically truncating output

Tags: php, python

I have a PHP script that calls a Python script which loops through a text file outputting specific lines to the webpage. The PHP script calls the Python script and echoes its output like this...

```
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo ($output);
```

The relevant Python code is this...

```
for myStr in myList:
    myObj=re.match(r'(\s|\S)+\[(?P<specificVal>\d+)(\s|\S)+',myStr)
    specificVal = int(myObj.group('specificVal'))
    if specificVal in range(min,max):
        print ('<p>%s</p>' % (myStr))
```

This works for about a hundred lines then it stops outputting, when there might be as many as a few thousand. Is there a better way to do this, or do I just need to edit some php.ini options? Thank you!

Comment: why mix the 2, why not just write it all in either python or php?

Comment: How are you generating `myList` in Python?  This almost definitely looks more like a python bug than a php one.

Comment: I'm assuming the Python script works properly when you run it without PHP?

Comment: @Dagon because parsing XML is a cakewalk in Python and absolute hell in PHP

Comment: Your python code doing a regex match may not be needed: `if 'specificVal' in myStr: print...`. Please post more of py code, even XML that PHP is a pain to handle -for us curious folks.

Comment: so make it ALL python then, and php dom parser seem to handle xml quite well from my experience

Answer (score 1):

This could have to do with `shell_exec()` not returning all of the output for some reason. You could try using the more-robust [proc_open()](https://secure.php.net/proc_open):

```
<?php

$fileDescriptors = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"), // STDIN
   1 => array("pipe", "w"), // STDOUT
   2 => array("pipe", "w")  // STDERR
);
$pipes = array();
flush();

$process = proc_open($command, $fileDescriptors, $pipes, realpath('.'), array());
if (!is_resource($process))
{
    error_log("Failed to execute '$command'");
    return;
}

while ($data = fgets($pipes[1]))
{
    print $data;
    flush();
}
```

You might gain some performance benefit from not calling `flush();` on every loop iteration as well.

If this still isn't giving you all of the output, I would be suspicious of a problem in the Python script, and you should post more of it to make it easier to debug.